# Grep using a regular expression and capturing using groups

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

I have multiple text files containing lines as below:
"""Version       : 3.4.0.0
xxx
xxx
xxx"""
I'm trying to capture 3.4.0.0 from each text file and display on the terminal.
the command i've written is this :

```
grep -m1 'Version[\s\S]*?(\d[\s\S]+?)\n' *.txt

grep -m1 'Version[\s\S]*?(\d[\s\S]+?)\n' *.txt
```

I'm unable to get any results using the above code. Can someone assist me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is a PCRE compliant regex, `[\s\S]` matches any char in a PCRE pattern, but not with POSIX BRE regex flavor that you are using with your `grep` since you did not use`-P` option.

If you want to do it with GNU grep use

```
grep  -oPm 1 'Version\s*:\s*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)+' *.txt
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/1UHQwg)

**Details**

- `Version` - `Version` string
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\d+` - 1+ digits and then
- `(?:\.\d+)+` - 1 or more repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits.

You may do that with `awk`:

```
awk '/^Version : [0-9]+/{print $3; exit}' *.txt
```

See the [online awk demo](https://ideone.com/GgN5v4):

```
s="Text
Version : 3.4.0.0 xxx xxx xxx
More text
Version : 5.6.0.0 xxx xxx xxx"
awk '/^Version : [0-9]+/{print $3; exit}' <<< "$s"
# => 3.4.0.0
```

**Details**

- `^Version : [0-9]+` finds a line that starts with `Version : <1 or more digits>`
- `{print $3; exit}` outputs the value of Field 3 and stops processing getting you just the first match.